# No instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::erase [with _Ty=Enemy *, _Alloc=std::allocator<Enemy *>]" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stl, erase

```
for (auto enemy : this->enemies)
{
    if (enemy->getHP() <= 0)
    {
        enemies.erase(enemy);
    }
}
```

I have a vector `enemies` containing multiple of `Enemy*` elements and i want to erase an enemy if their hp is 0 or below

I write the code above and it gave me this error message:

```
No instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::erase [with _Ty=Enemy *, _Alloc=std::allocator<Enemy *>]" matches the argument list
    argument types are: (Enemy*)
    object type is: std::vector<Enemy*,std::allocator<Enemy*>>
```

I assume that is not the right way to do it, so how?

Im new in stackoverflow and im still learning english so sorry if i made mistakes

EDIT:

It's my almost complete code:

```
struct enemyType
{
public:
    int type;
    sf::Vector2f pos;
}
std::vector<std::vector<enemyType>> enemyList = {
    {
        { trashMonster, sf::Vector2f(5.f * 16, 18.f * 16) }
    }
}
std::vector<Enemy*> enemies;
std::vector<Enemy*>* GetEnemy(int level)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < enemyList[level].size(); i++)
    {
        switch (enemyList[level][i].type)
        {
        case trashMonster:
            n_TrashMonster->setPosition(enemyList[level][i].pos);
            enemies.emplace_back(n_TrashMonster);
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Error to get an enemy\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    return &enemies;
}
//Code in different file
std::vector<Enemy*> enemies;
this->enemies = *GetEnemy(lvl);
for (auto enemy : this->enemies)
{
    enemy->update(player->getCollisionBox());
    //collision enemies to tilemap
    collision::MapCollision(*this->map.getTilesCol(), *enemy);
    if (enemy->getHP() <= 0)
    {
        enemies.erase(enemy);
    }
}
```

Didn't include that because my code is a complete mess so I was afraid people won't get the point of my question and it's my first question here

Comment: Please include a [mcve] so we don't need to guess what types things are.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre].

Comment: 1) This is not how `erase()` gets called. 2) Even if that's how `erase()` gets called the end result will be a spectacular crash. You cannot `erase()` anything from a vector and continue to iterate over it. This always ends in tears. Are you familiar with the C++ concepts of iterators, how they work, and `std::vector`'s specifications for iterator invalidations?

Comment: And for future questions please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: have a look at [std::erase_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2), you also migh consider to use `for (auto& enemy : this->enemies)` with a reference to avoid unecessary copying of data (but still not for deleting entries of the vector)

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `std::vector<T>::erase` function does not have a `erase(T a)` overload. And if you want to remove elemennts from a `vector` you can't iterate over them like that. I suggest a convencional loop.

```
for (size_t i=0; i<this->enemies.size();++i){
    if (this->enemies[i]->getHP()){
        std::swap(enemies[i],enemies::back());
        delete enemies::back();//Only if you don't free the space elsewere
        enemies.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Edit:
This will mess up the order of the vector. If you don't want that you can use `erase(enemies.begin()+i)` iinstead of swaping it back and removeing it

Comment: That's why there is std::erase_if :)

Comment: Only in C++20. Unfortunately not everyone uses C++20. Also if the order is not important my way is a bit faster

Comment: Fair points, sometimes hard to remember which feature is available from which version.

Answer (score 0):

When using STL containers usually you don't even need an (explicit) for loop. Use std::remove_if like this

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Enemy
{
public:
    // not explicit on purpose, so I can initalize vector more quickly (in real code you should have explicit constructors if they have one argument of a different type)
    Enemy(int hp) : 
        m_hp{ hp }
    {
    };

    int getHP() const noexcept
    {
        return m_hp;
    }

    int m_hp;
};

int main()
{
    // create a test vector with enemies with given hitpoints
    std::vector<Enemy> enemies{ 1,2,0,4,5,6,0,7,8 };

    // boolean lambda function that determines if an enemy is dead.
    auto enemy_is_dead = [](const Enemy& enemy) { return enemy.getHP() <= 0; };

    // use remove_if (this will move all the items to be removed to the end
    auto remove_from = std::remove_if(enemies.begin(), enemies.end(), enemy_is_dead );

    // then shrink the vector
    enemies.erase(remove_from, enemies.end());
    
    for (const auto& enemy : enemies)
    {
        std::cout << enemy.getHP() << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```